AR core function for newer TCL models
Ar core not compatible on TCL ion V Ar core should be allowed to be compatible on TCL ION V
I was going to see if Are core was compatible with my phone as it can most likely handle it and I come to find out the device can't handle it I download an APK of it and it works fine but can't play games that need Ar core so I got and check my Android model and check everything and everything is up to date I have an android version 13 and a MediaTek Helio G25 CPU so what is wrong?

The tag tcl is for a programming language, not a Chinese consumer goods manufacturer.

I was trying to use a tag for my phone brand
